# Overloading of = operator for a class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was recently refreshing my C++ knowledge in operator overloading. As recommended I return a reference to `*this` for the `operator overload of '='`. But then I found one problem :-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    int num = 4;
    public:
        MyClass() = default;
        MyClass(int x) : num(x) {}
        void getnum(int x)
        {
            num = x;
        }
        void shownum()
        {
            cout << num << '\n';
        }
        MyClass& operator = (const MyClass& obj)  // works even without const
        {
            this->num = obj.num;
            return *this;
        }
        ~MyClass() = default;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass x, y(5), z(7);

    z = MyClass(8) = y;   // temporary object return reference

    x.shownum();
    y.shownum();
    z.shownum();
}
```

This code doesnt result into a `UB` even though a temporary object `MyClass(8)` is involved in between which will be equated with `y` (fine no problem) but then it's reference will be sent to equate with `z`. Why doesn't the `dangling reference` problem occur here ? Why does the overload function work without `const MyClass&' on the temporary object 'MyClass(8)` ?

Comment: It is one of implicit conversions. It is perfectly legitimate to make an object more const volatile

Comment: Why are you considering writin such code

Comment: Experiment @EdHeal :-P

Comment: There's no such thing as "result into ... UB"; undefined behavior is a property of the **source code**, and it means **only** that the language definition doesn't tell you what a program that uses such code should do. It does **not** mean that something bad must happen. (Note, too, that there is no undefined behavior in the code in the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporaries live until the full expression ends. At the end the temporary goes away, but by then the assignments have all been performed and since you don't store the reference anywhere it's okay for the temporary to go away.

Comment: @OlzhasZhumabek they do

Comment: @Joachim `MyClass(8)` returns a reference to itself but my question is When it is destroyed as soon as it is used isn;t the reference that is sent to equate with `z` invalid now because the temporary has been destroyed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, nevermind. I got all answers I need from [gotw](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) :)

Comment: @AnkitAcharya No because the lifetime is until the *full* expression ends. I.e. after all two assignments have happened.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so according to you `MyClass(8)` isn't destroyed until the whole `z = MyClass(8) = y` expression has been evaluated ?

Comment: @AnkitAcharya Yes that's it.

Answer (score 4):

The first assignment `MyClass(8) = y;` returns a `MyClass&` that doesn't tell anything about being a temporary. And so it matches the parameter of the next `operator=`, whether that one expects a const or non-const parameter.

If you try to just assign a temporary `z = MyClass(8);`, you will see that it now requires the parameter to be a const reference.

Also, there are no dangling references here, because temporary objects live until the end of the full expression (usually at the `;`), and no pointers or references are saved anywhere. Just copies of the `num` values.

Comment: Ok that answers the second question. What about the first one ?

Comment: Right, two questions for the price of one. :-)